# AWS Lambda with API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

How to make the apigateway take the latest lambda code ? I have configured everything

CloudFront -> ApiGateway -> Lambda but when i make new changes to the lambda, those are not reflected. Old code gets executed.

Comment: Is the lambda actually executed or does cloudfront cache the request? Are you using versioning on the lambda, if so: do you publish it, do you use aliases, what version / alias does the api gateway point to?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I created the alias and no-caching in the cloudfront and it worked

Comment: @luk2302  Do yo know how to get the cloudfront hostname inside the lambda ? I get the API gateway domain name though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating lambda alias to point to latest version + no cache-policy in cloudfront worked for me.